# Fluid tap isn't showing

Tags: fluid-simulation

The fluid tap isn't showing for some reason, while all the other physic taps will.
it still won't show even if I only select fluid.
I just click others to show that only fluid isn't showing.
[image]

Comment: Not sure how, but don't have this problem anymore, it was a onetime bug I think.
after restarting my PC, it was gone.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely when you "opened" this blender file, check on your left lower size of the screen "LOAD UI" on the OPEN FILE manager. UNCHECK IT. THEN, open up the file.
If you already did, then yes, you need to "re-open it" like it was the first time you opened it, and uncheck the load UI.
If you have it save, close the file. Open file>uncheck load UI. Profit.